# Error in finding the edge map gradient of the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to find the edge map gradient of the image. I tried the following code

```
I=imread('Sub.png');
I=rgb2gray(I);
disp(' Compute edge map ...');
f = 1 - I/255;
figure, imshow(f,[]); title('edge map');
[fx,fy] = gradient(f);
figure, quiver(fx,fy);
title('edge map gradient');
```

image is
http://postimg.org/image/ba08la73v/

Error is

```
 Error using bsxfun
Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.

Error in gradient (line 68)
   g(2:n-1,:) = bsxfun(@rdivide,(f(3:n,:)-f(1:n-2,:)),h);
```

Comment: That's not the entire error.  Please post the **entire error**.

Comment: sir,i had posted entire error.I had added the image too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the nature of your image.  The [`gradient`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) function expects a `double` type image but you are providing a `uint8` image.  Either cast your image to `double`, or use [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) to convert the image into `double` precision.  However, `im2double` will normalize the intensities  between `[0,1]`.

So:

```
I=imread('Sub.png');
I=rgb2gray(I);

I = im2double(I); %Or: I = double(I) %// Change
disp(' Compute edge map ...');
%//f = 1 - I/255; %// Leave this if using double(I)

f = 1 - I; %// Change

figure, imshow(f,[]); title('edge map');
[fx,fy] = gradient(f);
figure, quiver(fx,fy);
title('edge map gradient');
```

The reason why the `f` statement is being calculated is so that the intensities are reversed.  White becomes black and black becomes white.  This is probably so that when you visualize the gradient, the shape will look convex and not concave... it'll be easier to visualize.

---

FWIW, I would suggest you use [`imgradientxy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradientxy.html) instead to help you find the gradient in each direction.  It's designed to operate on images:

Something like:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('Sub.png'));
[fx,fy] = imgradientxy(1 - im2double(I));
```

Comment: is there any difference between im2double(I) and double(I)

Comment: I HAD SEEN IN ONE CODE EDGE MAP AS F=1-i/255. CAN YOU EXPLAIN THE MEANING?

Comment: @abcd - BTW - if you want the image gradient, try taking a look at `imgradientxy` instead.  This is better for finding gradient images, and it also takes in images rather than converting to `double` first.

Comment: i tried hy = fspecial('sobel');
hx = hy';
Iy = imfilter(double(Img), hy, 'replicate');
Ix = imfilter(double(Img), hx, 'replicate');
gradmag = sqrt(Ix.^2 + Iy.^2);
is it correct as imgradientxy() ?

Comment: @abcd - No.  That's the behaviour of `imgradient`.  `imgradientxy` basically finds `hx` and `hy`.